# For loop in 'c'

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    for(;;);
    getch();
}
```

when compiled gives error unreachable code for getch()..
and when compiled without a semicolon if

```
void main()
{
    for(;;)
    getch();
}
```

then error is removed.  Can you please explain How this is working?

Comment: This is basic C syntax, which should be explained in any decent C book. StackOverflow is not generally a site for requesting tutorials.

Answer (score 5):

Indent your code to avoid such confusions. I personally always use `{}` to avoid such bugs.

```
for(;;); // Infinite for loop
getch(); // Runs after the for loop (thus unreachable)

for(;;)
   getch();  // Calls getch() for each iteration
```

Answer (score 3):

`for(;;);` should be thought of as

```
for(;;)
    ;
```

i.e. an infinite loop which constantly executes an empty statement.  Any code beyond this loop is unreachable, hence the warning.

Your second version should be thought of as

```
void main()
{
    for(;;)
        getch();
}
```

This is also an infinite loop but has no code following it so no unreachable code.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(;;);
```

is different from:

```
for(;;)
```

In first case the statement after the `for` is only executed ***after*** the for loop has completed execution.
This makes the `getch()` indeed unreachable, which your compiler complains for with diagnostic:

*unreachable code for `getch()`.*

In second case the statement after the `for` is executed on each iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `for(;;)` is an infinite loop. So if you put the `;` at the end, `fetch();` is never reached since it's outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`for(;;);`  Do nothing infinitely. So the rest of the code after this statement is unreachable and hence your error.

```
for(;;)
    getch();
```

Get character from the stdin infinitely

Answer (score 0):

```
for(;;);
```

asks for an infinite loop of ';' empty instruction.

Thus, any code following this loop will never be executed.